# AWS Elastic Transcoder: Pipeline not found

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I have an Elastic Transcoder pipeline configured, and it has successfully processed jobs created via the AWS Management Console. However, when using the Ruby API, the pipeline doesn't appear to exist:

```
et = AWS::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new
puts et.list_pipelines.inspect
# {:pipelines=>[], :request_id=>"e9e5ae2b-ca43-11e3-969d-530832cf62dd"}
```

Similarly, calling `create_job` with the correct `:pipeline_id` raises an error, claiming AWS returned a 404 for that pipeline ID.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/error-handling.html), this does *not* indicate a permissions error. A permissions error should return a 403. But just to be sure, I set the IAM user's permissions to superuser as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why would the pipeline not be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to the same AWS region in which your pipeline resides. To find out the pipeline's region:

1. Go to the list of pipelines in the AWS Management Console.
2. Click the magnifying glass icon for your pipeline. This should open the pipeline's details.
3. Find the region in the ARN string. For example, `us-west-2`.

Then, when you connect to AWS, do it like this:

```
AWS.config({
  :access_key_id => 'abc',
  :secret_access_key => '123',
  :region => 'us-west-2' # Or whatever your region is
})
```